# VSCode settings dont work when formatting code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Default Settings for VSCode have defined tabSize:

```
// The number of spaces a tab is equal to.
"editor.tabSize": 4,
```

[image]

Why, when I call Format Code, it makes tab indent only 2 spaces ??
Note, this tabSize setting is not overwritten anywhere, no custom settings.